# Having trouble mounting encrypted disk (ZFS) on Ubuntu

Tags: mount, encryption, luks, zfs

I have a new SSD to backup photos.
I installed Ubuntu 21.10, with ZFS and encrypted.
Everything worked well and I decided to backup some photos.

Now, I wanted to boot with my old encrypted disk (Ubuntu 21.04).
Nautilus can see the new Disk, but I get "incorrect passphrase".

I am trying to boot from the new disk, and I can not... I get:

```
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>_
```

When I run `sudo fdisk -l` I see:

```
....
Festplatte /dev/sdb: 1,82 TiB, 2000398934016 Bytes, 3907029168 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: SanDisk SDSSDH3 
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: 6B27A9CF-D016-4349-BD97-280DBA71F536

Gerät       Anfang       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sdb1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI-System
/dev/sdb2  1050624    5244927    4194304    2G Linux Swap
/dev/sdb3  5244928    9439231    4194304    2G Solaris Boot
/dev/sdb4  9439232 3907029134 3897589903  1,8T Solaris Root

....

Festplatte /dev/sda: 1,82 TiB, 2000398934016 Bytes, 3907029168 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: SanDisk SDSSDH3 
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: 0EB129CF-7358-4B35-811F-6BE5E873949D

Gerät       Anfang       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sda1     2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096    1054719    1050624  513M EFI-System
/dev/sda3  1054720    5249023    4194304    2G Linux Swap
/dev/sda4  5249024    9443327    4194304    2G Solaris Boot
/dev/sda5  9443328 3907029134 3897585807  1,8T Solaris Root
```

And then I am lost... I don´t know what is the next step to access to the Disk...

What can I try to fix this or to access to the disk?

Thanks in advance!